# Sql.Создание таблицы и работа с ней

Tags: sql

Имеется база данных на сервере, в ней таблица, надо создать поле,как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

[ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/alter-table.html)

Comment: не получилось, вместо table_name имя добавляемой таблицы вписать?

Comment: Вместо table_name впиши имя той таблицы, куда добавить поле + после COLUMN имя_поля тип_поля  